# IIS Url Rewrite with Capture Groups for First Item In List

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

Our application depends on the client IP address for various features. We've updated our infrastructure and changed how we load balance our application. Because of the change, the CGI.REMOTE_ADDR being reported to the application is that static load balancer IP not the client IP. To fix this, the LB support said to add a rule to both the LB and IIS. The LB is now configured to send a header [http_x_forwarded_for] with the client ip.

The rewrite rule in IIS looks like this:

```
                <rule name="REMOTE_ADDR rewrite" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                <match url="^((?!GetImage).)*$" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="REMOTE_ADDR blank URL rewrite" enabled="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.cfm" />
            </rule>
```

The first rule is for any pages requested excluding the GetImage page. The second is for no page.

For the most part this works correctly. We haven't had to make any adjustments to the application because the CGI.REMOTE_ADDR is correct.

But we were told that in some circumstances the LB may pass multiple IP addresses and to use only the first one in the list. This is causing a problem.

In some cases CGI.REMOTE_ADDR is coming through like this '100.200.200.200, 123,123,123,123'.

Testing the RegEx in IIS with that string shows group {R:0} is 100.200.200.200, 123,123,123,123.

The question is is it possible to write the rule so that {R:0} is the first matched IP address in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Realized after I posted this I was attacking it (or asking..) the wrong way.
The URL Rule regex is to match the URL to apply the rule. All requested URLS that match will map the http_x_forwarded_for header value into the REMOTE_ADDR server variable. The value of this variable which could be invalid what the problem.

To fix this, a new OUTBOUND rule needed to be added. In this rule you can specify the REMOTE_ADDR as the INPUT and matching against a regex to rewrite it. By adding the rule, a regex to match the first IP addr found in the variable, and then rewrite the variable with the back trace I was able to solve the problem.

```
            <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Format IP Address">
                <match serverVariable="REMOTE_ADDR" pattern="^([0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3})(.)*$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R;1}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
```